# Weird floating point shows up when input very large number in Python/Odoo

Tags: python, floating-point, odoo, odoo-10

I'm using Odoo v10 and I set the currency decimal places to 6.
When I input a number below 3,000,000,000,000 then the result is expected.
But when I input 3,000,000,000,000 or above. it will convert to 3,000,000,000,000.001465. I wonder why did that happen.
Is there any fix for this? I need the number to stay as I input it in the field.

[image: Odoo v10]

Comment: @ArndtJonasson: Floating-point representations do not turn integers into non-integers. A floating-point number is some number of base-*b* digits multiplied by *b* to some power. A floating-point operation that cannot produce an exact result drops low digits (rounding the remaining digits up or down). If a value is an integer, it cannot have any non-zero digits below the unit position, so dropping any low digits cannot add any non-integer value to it. There must have been some arithmetic performed on the value other than floating-point rounding.

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right. Half of my comment was correct, but not relevant here.